# Swift 4 Apple LLVM 9.0 Error Exit code 10

Tags: swift, error-handling

> Command/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 10

I am facing a strange issue. I haven't changed anything but my project is not able to build any more for some reason. 
This happened as I changed from Simulator to my phone (which I do really often) after the newest iOS Update.

The below errors came up all at once.
I tried everything from cleaning the project, restarting Xcode, reinstalling/updating pods, using different simulators and reattaching the iPhone new.

Any idea?

[image]

[image]

Comment: clean project, restart Xcode, delete derive data directory

Comment: Like I said that’s what I already done 3 times

Comment: After one day of resting and not doing anything it now seems to work again although I haven't changed anything.

Comment: xcode is very crazy manytimes

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Go to preferences -> Location -> derived data -> and the remove the derived data or give a custom location. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue suddenly, I closed everything then restart mac, then it worked